# Output isn't what I expected

Tags: python

I am writing a program using the while loop. I'm trying to write a program to ask the marital status and age of 3 people. The problem I am having is that if I put in an input other than "married", it doesn't add it to the right output. So what I'm asking is how do I make it so that when I put in an input of, for example, "single", the output says, `the number of people who are single is: 1`?
Here's my code:

```
marriedstud=0
sepstud=0
marriedover50=0
married40s=0
married30s = 0
married20s = 0
sepover50=0
sep40s=0
sep30s = 0
sep20s = 0
divorcedstud=0
divorcedover50=0
divorced40s = 0
divorced30s = 0
divorced20s = 0
singleover50=0
single40s=0
single30s=0
single20s = 0
singlestud=0
age=0
count = 0
while (count < 2):
    maritalstatus= input("Please enter persons marital status:")
    age =input("Please enter perons age: ")
    if (maritalstatus=="MARRIED") or (maritalstatus=="married"): #I tried using 'and' and 'or' but neither work
        marriedstud = marriedstud + 1
    if (age>=50):
        marriedover50 = marriedover50 + 1
    elif (age>=40) and (age<50):
        married40s = married40s + 1
    elif (age>=30) and (age<40):
        married30s = married30s + 1
    elif (age>=20) and (age<30):
        married20s = married20s + 1
    else:
        if (maritalstatus=="SINGLE") or (maritalstatus=="single"):
            singlestud = singlestud + 1
        if (age>=50):
            singleover50 = singleover50 + 1
        elif (age>=40) and (age<50):
            single40s = single40s + 1
        elif (age>=30) and (age<40):
            single30s = single30s + 1
        elif (age>=20) and (age<30):
            single20s = single20s + 1
        else:
            if (maritalstatus=="DIVORCED") or (maritalstatus=="divorced"):
                divorcedstud = divorcedstud + 1
            if (age>=50):
                divorcedover50 = divorcedover50 + 1
            elif (age>=40) and (age<50):
                divorced40s = divorced40s + 1
            elif (age>=30) and (age<40):
                divorced30s = divorced30s + 1
            elif (age>=20) and (age<30):
                divorced20s = divorced20s + 1
            else:
                if(maritalstatus=="SEPARATED") or (maritalstatus=="separated"):
                    sepstud = sepstud + 1
                if (age>=50):
                    sepover50 = sepover50 + 1
                elif (age>=40) and (age<50):
                    sep40s = sep40s + 1
                elif (age>=30) and (age<40):
                    sep30s = sep30s + 1
                elif (age>=20) and (age<30):
                    sep20s = sep20s + 1
    count += 1

print("The number of pepole who are married is: " +str(marriedstud))
print("The number of pepole who are married and over the 50 is: " +str(marriedover50))
print("The number of pepole who are married and in the age group of 40's is: " +str(married40s))
print("The number of pepole who are married and in the age group of 30's is: " +str(married30s))
print("The number of pepole who are married and in the age group of 20's is: " +str(married20s))
print("*****")
print("The number of pepole who are single is: " +str(singlestud))
print("The number of pepole who are single and over the 50 is: " + str(singleover50))
print("The number of pepole who are single and in the age group of 40's is: " +str(single40s))
print("The number of pepole who are single and in the age group of 30's is: " +str(single30s))
print("The number of pepole who are single and in the age group of 20's is: " +str(single20s))
print("*****")
print("The number of pepole who are divorced is: " +str(divorcedstud))
print("The number of pepole who are divorced and over the 50 is: " +str(divorcedover50))
print("The number of pepole who are divorced and in the age group of 40's is: " +str(divorced40s))
print("The number of pepole who are divorced and in the age group of 30's is: " +str(divorced30s))
print("The number of pepole who are divorced and in the age group of 20's is: " +str(divorced20s))
print("*****")
print("The number of pepole who are separated is: " +str(sepstud))
print("The number of pepole who are separated and over the 50 is: " +str(sepover50))
print("The number of pepole who are separated and in the age group of 40's is: " +str(sep40s))
print("The number of pepole who are separated and in the age group of 30's is: " +str(sep30s))
print("The number of pepole who are separated and in the age group of 20's is: " +str(sep20s))
print("*****")
```

Comment: What if `age = 50`, or `age = 40`…?!

Comment: @deceze That's not the reason why when I run it that the program doesn't count it towards the right status, except married

Comment: That's true. But it's a giant obvious flaw in your logic that needed pointing out.

Comment: The other big problem is that you're only checking `maritalstatus=="SINGLE"` if `age` didn't match any of your checks. If your logic worked correctly (see first comment), only people < 20 would ever be considered for single, divorced or separated.

Comment: @deceze Either I don't understand what you're saying or you're wrong. When I run the program all the ages I input get put into the right age group, but it only goes under the `married` status

Comment: Try to follow your own logic: if `age` is anywhere over 20, one of your `(el)if age ...` statements will match and increment the associated `married**` value. **Only if none of those `(el)if` match does it go into `else` and check any of the other conditions.** Or when do you expect the `else` to apply?

Comment: @deceze So should I just get rid of `else`?

Comment: What you probably want is to change the relationship of your `if..elif..else`s. You want `if (is married): ... elif (is single): ... elif (is divorced): ...` all **on the same level**, and within each of these blocks you want the age check. – Overall you'd want to *simplify* this a whole lot, but this would at least express what you want.

Comment: @deceze Ok great, I fixed thanks a lot. Just one more thing, can you at least give me a hint where if the user inputs something for marital status that's not defined, instead of the program stopping, it says `Sorry ! The marital status does not belong to one of the known statuses`

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

This is a clash between data types. When the user enters the age  after marital status, they enter it as a string, which you cannot compare with integers like 20,30,40, etc. you need to do this:

```
int(age)
```

instead of just:

```
age
```

please mark as correct if this helps

Comment: That is *also* an issue, but by far not the only one.

Comment: oh. Well, I looked at your profile and I am now going to get out of your way and let you answer the question

Comment: Quite honestly, this is the kind of question that does not have a very interesting problem, but takes a lot of effort to answer properly. I'm happy giving hints in the comments and hope somebody else writes up the proper answer it needs. ;)

Comment: Ok. Also, would you mind taking a look at a question that I asked a couple of hours ago? I think you'd be able to find it through my profile